# Ruby on Rails - template missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, missing-template

I'm a newbie with Ruby on Rails and I know that it is kind of tricky but I just can't find a solution for this online, even though it is supposed to be the easiest thing...

I have everything set up and have created a new controller + view with `rails generate controller welcome index` .

The files appear in the correct directories and I have a `index.html.erb` file in the `welcome` folder under `/app/views/welcome/`.

The routing file in `/config/` contains the appropriate routing to the controller

```
NewApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'welcome#index'
end
```

But even though I have everything set up correctly to my knowing I get this error:

```
Missing template welcome/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. 
Searched in: * "/Users/Constantin/Development/Rails [Ruby]/new-app/app/views"
```

I understand the error message. It tells me that it looks for some kind of template file in the named formats in the `views` folder of my application but I don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your project path for your rails app has has a folder with square brackets in the name (the folder titled `Rails [Ruby]`) :

```
/Users/Constantin/Development/Rails [Ruby]/new-app/app/views
```

Remove the square brackets from the folder name and restart your server.

For more information, check out this issue: [Rails projects do not work if project path contains open bracket "["](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6010)

Also change your `get` route to be like this:

```
get 'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: just used the regular URL after firing up the WeBrick. localhost:3000

Comment: Also. localhost:3000/welcome/index doesn't work either. Same error

Comment: Looking at your directory: `"/Users/Constantin/Development/Rails [Ruby]/new-app/app/views"` <~ does this mean you have a folder titled `"Rails [Ruby]"` with square brackets in your development machine? If so try removing the square brackets in your folder name (and then stop and restart your webrick server).